# Call a function on jQueryUI Slider change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, function, slider

i have this code:

```
$(function test() {
    alert ('changed');
});


$(function precio() {
    $( "#rango-precio" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 1000,
      values: [ 0, 1000 ],
      change: function (event, ui){ test(); },
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#monto" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
       }
    });
    $( "#monto" ).val( "$" + $( "#rango-precio" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#rango-precio" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

      });
```

I'd like to make it so that any change on the slider calls the `test` function, but it is not working. I have tried changing
`change: function (event, ui){  test();},`

to

`change: function (event, ui){  alert('changed')},`

That works, but I need to call a function when a change is made.
Any help please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you are autocalling this function at the begining :

```
$(function test() {
    alert ('changed');
});
```

But you aren't able to call the function again later. You can just set your function like this:

```
function test() {
    alert ('changed');
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5j8U/)**